# Data Analysis and Processing of Variables and their Concreteness

Tags: java, excel

I have a variable_text file with 100K variables (some unique, some not) and an excel file with (unique) variables in one column and their respective concreteness values in another column. I already wrote some code to read the variables from the text file and search their concreteness value from the excel file and spit out the results in another result_text file.

My problem is I need to use an appropriate data structure to store the variables and their concreteness and count the frequency of repeating variables from the variable_text file. I've looked at HashTables and HashMaps but dont know if I should chose from these or if there's another viable option.

This data structure must represent a sort of table or map:

Variable | Frequency | Concreteness

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that can help you with that, i recommend that you do use a hashmap like this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Map <String, Data> map = new HashMap <String, Data>();

String [] variables={"variable1", "variable2", "variable3", "variable4", "variable4", "variable1","variable1"};
int Concreteness=5;//for this example every variable will have the same cncreteness

for(int i=0; i<variables.length;i++)
{
    Data variable_exists=map.get(variables[i]);

    if(variable_exists!=null)
    variable_exists.setFrecuency(variable_exists.getFrecuency()+1);
    else
    map.put(variables[i], new Data(Concreteness,1));

}

for (Map.Entry<String, Data> entry : map.entrySet()) 
{ System.out.println("variable = " + entry.getKey() + ", Frecuency = " + entry.getValue().getFrecuency()+ ", Concreteness = " + entry.getValue().getConcreteness()); }
}
```

the output for this example would be

variable = variable4, Frecuency = 2, Concreteness = 5

variable = variable1, Frecuency = 3, Concreteness = 5

variable = variable2, Frecuency = 1, Concreteness = 5

variable = variable3, Frecuency = 1, Concreteness = 5

and here is the Data class i used

```
public class Data
{
    private int frecuency;
    private int Concreteness;

    Data (int Concreteness, int frecuency)
    {
    setFrecuency(frecuency);
    setConcreteness(Concreteness);
    }
    public int getFrecuency()
    {
    return frecuency;
    }

    public void setFrecuency(int frecuenxy)
    {
    this.frecuency = frecuenxy;
    }

    public int getConcreteness()
    {
    return Concreteness;
    }

    public void setConcreteness(int Concreteness)
    {
    this.Concreteness = Concreteness;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply, you really helped me out here. If I can ask another question: How can I sort this on frequencies (Descending)?